# Latest ADAL not able to generate bearer token

Tags: c#, azure, token, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to generate authcontext with below code with the latest version of ADAL package (3.13.9) I am getting exception. However, I downgrade the ADAL version to v2.22.302111727 it works without an issue. I am using visual studio 2017. What is wrong with 3.13.9?

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);
```

> System.TypeInitializationException occurred   HResult=0x80131534
>   Message=The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext'
>   threw an exception.
>   Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory   StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext..ctor(String
>   authority, Boolean validateAuthority)    at
>   DestinationProvider.AADToken.d__4.MoveNext() in
>   D:\Repo\MyProjects\nv\nv\DestinationProvider\AADToken.cs:line 32    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at ReplLoop.ReplLoop.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   D:\Repo\MyProjects\nv\nv\nvReplLoop\ReplLoop.cs:line 52
>
> Inner Exception 1: TypeInitializationException: The type initializer
>   for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin'
>   threw an exception.
>
> Inner Exception 2: AdalException: Assembly required for the platform
>   not found. Make sure assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform,
>   Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   exists
>
> Inner Exception 3: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform,
>   Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you fix this issue now? If not, please don't hesitate to let me know which step block you.

Comment: Actually No. I switched to  v2.22.302111727 which works. 3.13.9 and 3.13.8 both giving the same error.

Comment: The issue is casued by the incorrect assembly reference.To narrow down the issue, you can create a fresh project and only install the `3.13.9` version of ADAL and compare the the version of assemblies then add the library one by one to check which library cause this issue. If you still have the problem, you may share a code project on GitHub to help to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have hit this issue:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/511

I'm using [isabekyan's workaround](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/511#issuecomment-269236641), as that has resolved the issue for me.

They suggest adding a call to the below code before using authenticationContext

```
  private static void SomeMethodToLinkPlatform()
    {
        var creds = new UserPasswordCredential("testUser", "SomePassword");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the reference is incorrect. If you were refer to the `3.13.9` version of ADAL, it shouldn't try to load the `3.13.8.999` version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform`.

Please ensure that the other assemblies you were referring is not depending on this library. Then you can use the Nuget to update the ADAL to the latest version(`3.13.9.1126`). After you upgrade, both the version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform` should be `3.13.9.1126`.

Please let me know if it helps.